# returning rows from an implicit JOIN where results either exist in both tables OR only one table

Tags: postgresql, select

I've got a PostgreSQL-9.0.x database that manages an automated testing environment.  There are a bunch of tables that contain assorted static data (OS versions, test names, etc) named 'buildlist' & 'osversmap'.  However, there are also two tables which contain data which changes often.  The first is a 'pending' table which is effectively a test queue where pending tests are self-selected by the test systems, and then deleted when the test run has completed.  The second is a 'results' table which contains the test results as they are produced (in progress and completed).

The records in the pending table have a one to many relationship with the records in the results table (each row in pending can have 0 or more rows in results).  For example, if no test systems have self-assigned a pending row, then there will be zero associated rows in results, and then once a pending row is assigned, the number of rows in results will increase for each pending row.  An added catch is that I always want only the newest results table row associated with each pending table row.  What I need to do is query the 'pending' table for pending tests, and then also get a 'logurl' from the results table that corresponds to each pending table row.

All of this is rather similar to this problem, except that I have the added burden of the two additional tables with the static data (buildlist & osversmap):
[PHP/SQL: Using only one query, SELECT rows from two tables if data is in both tables, or just SELECT from one table if not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343857/php-sql-using-only-one-query-select-rows-from-two-tables-if-data-is-in-both-ta)

I'm stumbling over how to integrate those two tables with static data into the query.  The following query works fine as long as there's at least one row in the 'results' table that corresponds to each row in the pending table (however, it doesn't return anything for rows that only exist in 'pending' yet not yet in 'results'):

```
SELECT 
 pending.cl,
 pending.id,
 pending.buildid,
 pending.build_type,
 pending.active,
 pending.submittracker,
 pending.os,pending.arch,
 pending.osversion,
 pending.branch,
 pending.comment,
 osversmap.osname,
 buildlist.buildname,
 results.logurl 
FROM pending ,osversmap ,buildlist ,results 
WHERE 
 pending.buildid=buildlist.id 
 AND pending.os=osversmap.os 
 AND pending.osversion=osversmap.osversion 
 AND pending.owner='$owner' 
 AND pending.completed='f' 
 AND results.hostname=pending.active 
 AND results.submittracker=pending.submittracker 
 AND pending.cl=results.cl 
 AND results.current_status!='PASSED' 
 AND results.current_status NOT LIKE '%FAILED' 
ORDER BY pending.submittracker,pending.branch,pending.os,pending.arch
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you define the "most recent result" record for a given pending record?

Comment: That's actually a bit of a clever hack.  The most recent result will always have "results.current_status!='PASSED' AND results.current_status NOT LIKE '%FAILED'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following work for you?

```
SELECT  pending.cl,
        pending.id,
        pending.buildid,
        pending.build_type,
        pending.active,
        pending.submittracker,
        pending.os,
        pending.arch,
        pending.osversion,
        pending.branch,
        pending.comment,
        osversmap.osname,
        buildlist.buildname,
        results.logurl
FROM pending
    JOIN osversmap
        ON ( pending.os = osversmap.os
            AND pending.osversion = osversmap.osversion )
    JOIN buildlist
        ON ( pending.buildid = buildlist.id )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN results
        ON ( pending.active = results.hostname
            AND pending.submittracker = results.submittracker
            AND pending.cl = results.cl 
            AND results.current_status != 'PASSED'
            AND results.current_status NOT LIKE '%FAILED'
            )
WHERE pending.owner = '$owner'
    AND pending.completed = 'f'
ORDER BY pending.submittracker,
    pending.branch,
    pending.os,
    pending.arch
```

Answer (score 0):

> All of this is rather similar to this problem, except that I have the added burden of the two additional tables with the static data (buildlist & osversmap):

Simplest approach would be to build a view that returns the right rows without referencing buildlist and osversmap. Then join those two tables to the view.

```
CREATE VIEW your-meaningful-view-name AS
SELECT 
 pending.cl,
 pending.id,
 pending.buildid,
 pending.build_type,
 pending.active,
 pending.submittracker,
 pending.os,pending.arch,
 pending.osversion,
 pending.branch,
 pending.comment,
 results.logurl 
FROM pending
-- No DDL or sample INSERT statements. You might need an outer join.
INNER JOIN results 
        ON (results.hostname=pending.active AND
            results.submittracker=pending.submittracker AND
            results.cl=pending.cl)
WHERE pending.owner='$owner' AND
      pending.completed='f' AND
      -- Are *both* these really necessary?
      results.current_status!='PASSED' AND
      results.current_status NOT LIKE '%FAILED'
```

And then

```
SELECT  osversmap.osname, buildlist.buildname, ymvn.*,
FROM your-meaningful-view-name ymvn
INNER JOIN osversmap ON ymvn.os=osversmap.os  
                    AND ymvn.osversion=osversmap.osversion 
INNER JOIN buildlist ON ymvn.buildid=buildlist.id 
ORDER BY ymvn.submittracker, ymvn.branch, ymvn.os, ymvn.arch
```